# Do all arrays contain pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

My understanding is that the values of arrays of characters are all pointers, not the actual ASCII integers.

Is the same true for all other arrays? For example, an array of structures. Is the $i$th element of that array a pointer to the $i$th structure?

Comment: Array of `char`s contains characters, not pointers.

Comment: Arrays of T contain instances of T, not pointers to T.

Comment: ***My understanding is that the values of arrays of characters are all pointers*** Your understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your understanding is very very wrong.

An array is a sequence of type T in contiguous memory. An array of chars is the easiest to visualize - an array of 8 chars will be an 8 byte block of memory. On a system with 4 bytes integers, an array of 8 integers will be a block of 8*4 = 32 bytes. If `struct T` has a sizeof 32 bytes then an array of 8 struct Ts will be 8*32 = 256 bytes. All of that should convince you that an array is actual objects, not pointers to items. Where the confusion probably arises is that you can use arrays and pointers somewhat interchangeably. Let me illustrate with ints and we'll come back to chars.

`int intArray[10]` is an array of 10 integers. You can treat `intArray` as an array or an `int*` like this:

```
int intArray[10] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600 ,700, 800, 900, 1000};
int* p = intArray;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::cout << "*p = " << *p << "\n";
    std::cout << "[" << i << "] = " << intArray[i] << "\n";
    p++;
}
```

This is the same behavior that lets you treat an array of chars as a string.

```
char charArray[4];
char *p = charArray;
// Insert characters one by one - no pointers here
charArray[0] = 'H';
charArray[1] = 'i';
charArray[2] = '.';
charArray[3] = 0;
// We can just use the pointer because char* is often assumed to be a 0
// terminated string.
std::cout << "p='" << p << "'\n";
std::cout << "charArray='" << charArray << "'\n";
```

There is a common convention that a char* is assumed to be a 0 terminated array of chars that can be used as a string but it does not have to be. You can just have an array of chars that are not 0 terminated. Kust like any other array it is up to you to remember the length.

```
char cA[4] = { 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69 };
std::cout << "cA='" << cA << "\n";
// UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR. cA is not 0 terminated
```

Comment: Add something about how an array is represented in memory, and what the `intArray` is actually (a pointer to 10 ints stacked next to eachother)

Comment: @pepperjack No, `intArray` is *not* a pointer. It's an array.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I didn't mean it was straight up a pointer, I meant explain how it functions like a pointer. Sorry.

Comment: @pepperjack It doesn't function like a pointer for about anything but the `operator []`  syntax, and that's not limited to or special for arrays and pointers either.

Comment: @BaummitAugen read the answer, he's already explained it as a pointer. That's all I wanted.